# Using CSS to resize multiple images

Tags: html, css

I have a large image split into many smaller images. I want them all to resize together if the browser window is resized. My code so far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <style>
        .splitimage{
        max-height:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        width:auto;
        }
        .keeptogether{
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        white-space:nowrap;
        line-height:0;
        word-spacing:-4px; 
        }
        </style>
        <div class="keeptogether">
            <div class="keeptogether">
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-0-0.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-0-1.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-0-2.jpeg" />
            </div>
            <br class="keeptogether">
            <div class="keeptogether">
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-1-0.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-1-1.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-1-2.jpeg" />
            </div><br class="keeptogether">
            <div class="keeptogether">
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-2-0.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-2-1.jpeg" />
                <img class="splitimage" src="worldmap-2-2.jpeg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but the images do not resize when the browser window shrinks.
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntL9c5jt/

Comment: Your fiddle resizes the images perfectly when the window shrinks...?

Comment: Ahh. It's supposed to be a **complete** world map...? I have a feeling this might be possible if you put them into a table. Otherwise I'm not sure. Why not just have one image?

Comment: actually image is getting re-size. since 1st cell of three occupy 100% so u are not able to see rest 2 images.   
for class`.splitimage` add width  as 33.3%. https://jsfiddle.net/ntL9c5jt/1/

Comment: Better still -- `calc(100%/3)`

Comment: I'd recommend to use just one single image instead of these 9 splitted images (page loading time, complex html etc.)

Comment: Thanks all. It is split into 512 images but I simplified it for this post. I was struggling to use the image map & area tags so I split the image so I could put link on certain sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add width as 33.3%. to the cells `.splitimage`

Answer (score 1):

set images width to 33.3333% - so, they will all together constitute to 100% of screen

```css
.splitimage {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 33.3333%;
    /* as there are 3 images in a line*/
  }
  .keeptogether {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0;
    word-spacing: -4px;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="keeptogether">
    <div class="keeptogether">
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-0-0.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-0-1.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-0-2.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <br class="keeptogether">
    <div class="keeptogether">
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-1-0.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-1-1.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-1-2.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <br class="keeptogether">
    <div class="keeptogether">
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-2-0.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-2-1.jpeg" />
      <img class="splitimage" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap-2-2.jpeg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```